# EntityManager cannot use persist to save element to database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, entitymanager

I met the problem of persisting element to database using EntityManager. Based on the  answers I found, I tried those 4 ways in my DaoJpa to do such thing but still failed. Here I attached the four ways I tried:

Code in Controller part:

```
   @Transactional 
   SmartProduct smartProduct = new SmartProduct();
            smartProduct.setName("Dove Soap");
            smartProductDao.persist(smartProduct);
```

1.
    DaoJpa:

```
 @Transactional
 public void persist(SmartProduct smartProduct) {
            entityManager.persist(smartProduct);
```

Doesn't work!

2.

```
@Transactional
public void persist(SmartProduct smartProduct) {
entityManager.persist(smartProduct);
entityManager.flush();
```

> Exception I got: no transaction is in progress

3.

```
@Transactional
public void persist(SmartProduct smartProduct) {
EntityTransaction emTransaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
        emTransaction.begin();  
        entityManager.persist(smartProduct);
        emTransaction.commit();
        entityManager.close();
```

> Exception I got:
>       Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring 
>       transactions or EJB CMT instead

4.

```
@Transactional
public void persist(SmartProduct smartProduct) {
                    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistenceUnit");
                EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
                EntityTransaction etx = em.getTransaction();
                etx.begin();
                em.persist(smartProduct);
                etx.commit();
                em.close();
                emf.close();
```

> Exception I got:
>       The application must supply JDBC connections

Could someone help me  figure out the problem please? Many thanks in advance!

Many thanks JustinKSU's help. I add the annotation in Spring context and then it solved!
Here is the previous version of my Spring context:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
```

After added the

```
<tx:annotation-driven />
```

it works:

```
<tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: Have you tried using @Transactional on the persist method?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it in the post. Yes I added @Transactional before the method in all the four ways. Also I tried to add (readOnly = true)/(readOnly = false)after Transactional annotation, and even added (propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED) as well, but seems no difference.

Comment: Are you using @PersistenceContext to inject the entityManager?

Comment: Yes I added it at the beginning of the controller: @PersistenceContext
 private EntityManager entityManager;

Comment: If you are using annotations do you have this in your Spring context  <tx:annotation-driven /> along with defining a transactionManager injecting the entity manager?

Comment: I checked the beans in Spring Elements, and under the section of Transactional there is "context:component-scan smartProductDaoJpa" which is the Jpa I use entityManager to persist things. but not sure whether is this the context you mentioned

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To enable @Transactional in your Spring context you should have the following:

Appropriate for your version of Spring:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">
```

Enable the annotations:

```
<tx:annotation-driven />
```

Declare your transaction manager injecting your entity manager:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I found that the annotation in my spring context is like this:<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/> should I modified any in this?

Comment: Try removing the mode parameter in going with the default mode="proxy"

Comment: Wow Thank you so much @JustinKSU I solve the problem now! It's exactly the problem of annotations! Maybe I should attached the content of my spring context below to help others who might also meet similar problem. Anyway, many many thanks for your kindly help!

Comment: @JustinKSU I tried as per your answer Please see http://pastie.org/9977330 and when I run it then I get error like it http://pastie.org/9977329

Comment: @SpringLearner  I suggest you ask your own question and the community may be able to help you.  Comments is not meant for things like this.  In your question you can link this answer if you feel it is relevant.  Off the top of my head, a common issue is having a mix of Spring versions.

Comment: @JustinKSU I have already posted a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28667550/how-to-rollback-in-entitymanager-createnativemethod Hope you can help there

Answer (score 1):

If you still have this problem and all the configurations are ok, please make sure that the @Transaction annotated method is public, not protected in order to be identified/managed by the transaction manager.

Comment: As per the code snippets in OP's post all methods are `public`. Also it states that when added `<tx:annotation-driven />` solves the problem. I don't see your answer adding anything to the discussion.

Comment: Maybe this answer could help other developers ?!