# Application using JPA does not save to database

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to save some object in my database but `entityManager.prestis()` doesn't work.
I'm using Spring MVC with the `@Transactional` annotation.

I was looking for sollution, but most of them said add:

```
<tx:annotation-driven />
```

It doesnt't resolve my problem, so there is my code, maybe someone could help me.

## CategoryDaoImpl.class

```
@Repository("categoryDao")
public class CategoryDaoImpl implements CategoryDao {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CategoryDaoImpl.class);

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }

    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Category> findAll() {
        return entityManager.createQuery("from Category c").getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Category findById(Long id) {
        return entityManager.find(Category.class, id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public Category save(Category category) {
        entityManager.persist(category);
        return category;
    }
}
```

## applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties" />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.dance.dancebook" />
    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000" />
        <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3" />
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000" />
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT version();" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
        id="transactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

     <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        id="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>  
</beans>
```

## root-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml" />

</beans>
```

## web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
        and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Spring MVC filters -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>HttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>singleSession</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>flushMode</param-name>
            <param-value>AUTO</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>HttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

## servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <resources location="/, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/"
        mapping="/resources/**" />

    <default-servlet-handler />      

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.dance.dancebook" />

    <interceptors>
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.ThemeChangeInterceptor" />
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor"
            p:paramName="lang" />
    </interceptors>

    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"
        id="messageSource" p:basenames="WEB-INF/i18n/messages,WEB-INF/i18n/application"
        p:fallbackToSystemLocale="false" />

    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver"
        id="localeResolver" p:cookieName="locale" />

    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource"
        id="themeSource" />
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.CookieThemeResolver"
        id="themeResolver" p:cookieName="theme" p:defaultThemeName="standard" />


     <!-- Tiles Configuration -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver" id="tilesViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView"/>
    </beans:bean> 

    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer" id="tilesConfigurer">
        <beans:property name="definitions">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>/WEB-INF/layouts/layouts.xml</beans:value>
                <!-- Scan views directory for Tiles configurations -->
                <beans:value>/WEB-INF/views/views.xml</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSource"/>
    </beans:bean>        

    <!-- Enable file upload functionality -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" id="multipartResolver"/>


</beans:beans>
```

## persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            <!-- value="create" to build a new database on each run; value="update" 
                to modify an existing database; value="create-drop" means the same as "create" 
                but also drops tables when Hibernate closes; value="validate" makes no changes 
                to the database -->
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <!-- Uncomment the following two properties for JBoss only -->
            <!-- property name="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl" value="false" / -->
            <!-- property name="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners" value="false" 
                / -->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

## Hibernate SQL output

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
```

I tried all options from [EntityManager cannot use persist to save element to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937394/entitymanager-cannot-use-persist-to-save-element-to-databasesolved) and have same problems, but sollution doesn't resolve my.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Please show us the servlet-context.xml.

Comment: can you please share the error log?

Comment: @RishiRock There is no log error, nothing happend

Comment: @JBNizet I added servlet-context.xml, also added persistence.xml

Comment: The servlet-context should not scan classes that are already scanned, and under the responsibility, of the root context. Make sure that component-scan only scans web-related components (i.e. controllers, but not the services and DAOs scanned by the root context)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To mark this question as answered:

The problem is that the servlet-specific context re-scans (and thus redefines, without applying the transactional settings) the beans (services and DAOs) that are defined by the root context. As a result, the controller gets a reference to the non-transactional redefined bean, instead of getting a reference to the transactional, original bean.

Comment: After googleing "spring jpa hibernate no save database no error message" this comment solved my problem (I literally configured everything found on the internet :) Thanks pal!