# how to rollback in entitymanager createNativeMethod

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa

I am using native method of entity manager and I want to rollback when some error occurs.For this I tried `@Transactional` annotation but this does not rollback.Below is my sample code

controller

```
@Autowired
ServiceImpl ServiceImpl;

@RequestMapping("/saveinfo")
@ResponseBody
@Transactional
public String saveinfo(Long id)
{
   ServiceImpl.saveInfo(id);
}
```

Service class

```
@Autowired
DAOImpl daoImpl;

@Transactional
public String saveinfo(Long id)
{
    daoImpl.saveInfo1(id);
    daoImpl.saveInfo12(id);
    daoImpl.saveInfo12(id);

}
```

DAO class

```
@Override
public BigInteger saveInfo11() {

   Query query =  entityManagerUtil.entityManager().createNativeQuery("insert query");
   return (BigInteger)query.getSingleResult();
}

@Override
public BigInteger saveInfo12() {

   Query query =    entityManagerUtil.entityManager().createNativeQuery("insert query");
   return (BigInteger)query.getSingleResult();
}

@Override
public BigInteger saveInfo13() {

   Query query =    entityManagerUtil.entityManager().createNativeQuery("insert query");
   return (BigInteger)query.getSingleResult();
}
```

Now in the above codes,

If I have some runtime error in `saveInfo3()` then I want to rollback methods of 
`saveInfo1()` and `saveInfo2()`

This is the way I did but it did not rollback,so Please tell me how to do

**EDIT**

I tried using

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=MyException.class,propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED) and  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED) and

@Transactional(rollbackFor=MyException.class))
```

In all the 3 cases ,it did not rollback

**Update**

```
applicationcontext.xml



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" 
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
       xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd        
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd         
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd         
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd         
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd 
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/task  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">



     <!--<context:annotation-config />-->
     <context:spring-configured/>

       <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
       </bean>
       <bean id="messageDigestPasswordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.MessageDigestPasswordEncoder">
         <constructor-arg value="SHA-256" />
        </bean>

       <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"  id="dataSource">
         <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>


    </bean>










     <tx:annotation-driven  mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
       <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/database.properties"/>
       <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/project.properties"/>

      <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
     </bean>

    <bean id="propertiesUtil" class="com.work.project.utils.PropertiesUtil">

    <property name="locations" >
   <list>
                <value>classpath*:META-INF/*.properties</value>

            </list>
    </property>

</bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.work.project">
        <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
    </context:component-scan>



     <task:executor id="myexecutor" pool-size="5"  />
<task:annotation-driven executor="myexecutor"/>








</beans>
```

modified controller method

```
@Autowired
ServiceImpl ServiceImpl;

@RequestMapping("/saveinfo")
@ResponseBody
//Now I dont use transactional annotation in controller class
public String saveinfo(Long id)
{
   ServiceImpl.saveInfo(id);
}
```

If any more information is required please ask

Comment: I just answered a very similar [question today](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28696152/spring-transactional-not-starting-a-transaction/28704004#28704004), it might be the same issue. Basically you're using annotation-driven mode="aspectj" but I don't see a `load-time-weaver` defined anywhere in your context.

Comment: @user2264997 If I make `<tx:annotation-driven  mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>` to  `<tx:annotation-driven/>` then my application fails to start.I mean when I right on the project and select run on server then it does not start.Wait I will post the error

Comment: @user2264997 please see this [error](http://pastie.org/9980637)

Comment: What version of Spring do you use? Can you confirm that the methods annotated with `@Transactional` are in a Spring Bean (defined in the XML file), that gets injected somewhere by Spring itself?

Comment: Could you show me how `entityManagerUtil` is obtained (injected?) and the code of `EntityManagerUtil.entityManager()`?

Comment: @AndreiI Please this http://pastie.org/9980724 and I am using spring 3

Comment: Try adding `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)` to both `saveInfo(id)` and `saveInfo11()`, `saveInfo12()`, `saveInfo13()`. Another question: what database are you using?

Comment: @AndreiI this is my room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44929/java-spring-jpa-php-jquery-javascript-beginners ,If possible come here

Comment: Please, post the code and/or configuration for `entityManagerUtil` bean.

Comment: @RomanC Please come to my chat room

Comment: I am so glad I dont have this XML configuration stuff anymore. It is time they create a DSL on top of that. So many characters just to express simple everyday configuration needs. Shame... .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the `EntityManager` is not injected by Spring. The `EntityManager` instance is created by your utility class `entityManagerUtil.entityManager()`. This means, that everytime when you use a new `EntityManager`, they are not part of your method transaction.

In order to solve this problem: let Spring inject correctly the `EntityManager` (try for example injecting it directly in your original bean with `@PersistenceContext` and do those three methods directly in the same single method).

---

UPDATE:
The problem was that the code that threw the exception was in a try/catch block, this way, the transaction was not rolled-back by Spring. Transaction is rolled-back only when the transactional method exits with an `RuntimeException` (by default).

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your method to have `rollbackFor` property for your `@Transactional` annotation, so that

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=MyException.class)
public String saveinfo(Long id)
```

Keep in mind, that `MyException` should be unchecked exception, as checked exceptions thrown from `@Transactional` method will not result transaction to be rolled back.

**Update:**

To make sure everything is correct

1. Check that Spring indeed creates proxy and your method is being executed in transaction (e.g. use [TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronizationManager.html))
2. Check that `MyException.class` is indeed unchecked exception (subclass of `java.lang.RuntimeException` or `java.lang.Error`)
3. Check that your exception is indeed thrown (e.g. not catched somehow)

And why your controller `saveInfo()` is marked as transactional? This it not recommended, only service layer should be marked as transactional. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118789/spring-mvc-controller-shouldnt-be-transactional-why) post for example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,I have tries this before it did not rollback.This rollback only occurs in HQl but not for native queries

Comment: Can you please update your question with the code you tried? (I updated my answer with some info)

Comment: I have modified the question

Comment: Looks like everything is correct. So rollback should work. Just one more time make sure that 1. Spring indeed creates transaction (use TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()) 2. MyException is unchecked exception 3. MyException is indeed thrown

Comment: see this http://pastie.org/9974005 after saveinfo1 and saveinfo2 is run,it will throw nullpointerexception on line 8.So what ever I have inserted in saveinfo1 and saveinfo2 should be rolledback but it did not happen.I check in DB,all the present there

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the entityManagerUtil (which you use within your DAO implementation) uses or creates an entity manager, that is not running in the surrounding transaction context. Please have a look at following [tutorial](https://techannotation.wordpress.com/2012/05/29/5-minutes-with-jpa-transaction/): Here the JPA EntityManager is injected with @PersistenceContext

Comment: Sorry, didn't saw it - you were 2min faster.

Answer (score 0):

Can you  make sure that your `persistenceUnit` has configured the following, `transaction type`(optional) and `hibernate.connection.autocommit` to `false`, if not please do so.

```
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

I have excluded other properties for brevity

Comment: I am using JPA not hibernate

Comment: Which JPA implementation?

Comment: spring JPA implementation

Comment: Well, Spring doesn't implement JPA, it requires you to specify jpaVendorAdapter/JPA Implementation , now which one are you using?

Comment: I did not understand your question

Comment: Anyhow the main point is for you set auto commit to false., which is true by default , even though you don't know which JPA provider you are working with , I have assumed hibernate, but point is same for whichever

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72017/discussion-between-springlearner-and-iamiddy).