# Spring @Transactional not starting a transaction

Tags: spring, maven-3, spring-transactions

I have a **multi-module Maven project** with the following structure:

```
project
  |
   -- data
       |
        -- DepartmentRepository.java
  |
   -- domain
       |
        -- Department.java
  |
   -- service
       |
        -- DepartmentService.java
       |
        -- DepartmentServiceImpl.java
  |
   -- web
       |
        -- DepartmentController.java
```

The project uses Spring 4.1.4, Spring Data JPA 1.7.2 and Maven 3.1.0.  The following classes are included:

```
@Entity class Department {}

interface DepartmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Department, Long> {}

interface DepartmentService {
  List<Department> getAll();
}

@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
class DepartmentServiceImpl implements DepartmentService {
  @Autowired
  private DepartmentRepository departmentRepository;

  @Transactional
  public List<Department> getAll() {
    return departmentRepository.findAll();
  }
}
```

I was hoping that as soon as the code enters `DepartmentServiceImpl.getAll`, a transaction would have been started.  However, I am finding that this is not the case.  No transaction is started.  I have checked this by examining `TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()` inside this method, which prints `false`.  I have also checked by putting break points in `TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction`.  However, as soon as `departmentRepository.findAll` is invoked, a transaction is correctly started (since `SimpleJpaRepository`, the class which provides an implementation of the JPA repository interface is also annotated with `@Transactional`).

A complete sample application demonstrating the problem is available on [Github](https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-mvc-transaction).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed your `annotation-driven` mode is set to `aspectj`

```
<transaction:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"/>
```

but you don't seem to have [`load-time-weaver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw-spring) defined anywhere in your context.

That may or may not be the issue as I only took a quick look. Also, I don't see why you would need `aspectj` vs the default `proxy` mode with what you have, so you might be fine just removing the `mode="aspectj"` altogether and default to proxy.

Comment: I changed `<transaction:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"/>` to `<transaction:annotation-driven/>` in the sample application to get the transactions to work.